Unable to install Visual Studio 2022
I'm unable to install visual studio 2022 on my virtual machine (widows 10, 32 Go of RAM), i get this weird error every time I run the installer:
Could not load file or assembly 'VSInstallerElevationService.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*********' ore one of its dependecies.File was not found? 
Has anyone already experienced this issue?

Will it load OK on a Win11 VM? I've had bother with installing both it and Intel's ICX compiler on older OS machines. In one instance it took exception to my graphics card (or rather the lack of one compatible with some features I had no intention of using).
